# Puzzle: Forced game end in at most two halfmoves

Tags: problems, checkmate, stalemate

Compose a position where

1. It's White to move
2. White can deliver checkmate or stalemate in 1 move
3. Or if they make a different move, then Black can deliver checkmate or stalemate in one 1 move

I needed 6 white pieces and 11 black pieces. Beat me!

Toned down example for understanding:

```
[FEN "7k/7P/7K/6BP/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 0"]
```

After the next White move, Black is either mated or stalemated, depending on if White plays Bf6 or not. (This does not meet the 3rd requirement).

Comment: Sry but wat does 6w+11b mean?

Comment: 6 white pieces and 11 black pieces?

Comment: How is white getting stalemated or checkmated possible in your above example? Plus, black can't even move if white plays Bf6#. But in your condition, it says *Latest after Black's answer it's game over*.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish: "Toned down example" - with only two possible outcomes. NO example for the wanted position!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one piece fewer, but how about:

```
[FEN "5brr/4p1pq/4P1pk/4N1p1/6P1/6PK/6PP/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.Nd7= {Black stalemated} (1.Nf7#) (1.Nxg6 Kxg6#) (1.Nxg6 Qxg6= {White stalemated})
```

Comment: Valid! (1.N~=, 1.Nf7#, 1.Nxg6 Kxg6#, 1.Nxg6 Qxg6=)

Comment: Accepted for now, although maybe it still can be economized. E.g. consider the far lighter Kh3 Qb4 Pg2 - Kh5 Ph6 Pg6 Pg5 Ph4 Pg3. Almost! (Qg4#, Qa5=, Qxh4 gxh4=, Qa6 g4#, but after Qf4 Black can choose g4+, game over in 1.5 instead of 1. Too bad!)

Comment: Can an acceptance be withdrawn? This still seems early days for this challenge

Comment: @Laska The OP can always change their mind about accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I knew it! 13 pieces:

```
[FEN "8/6p1/6P1/6PB/6P1/4p1pQ/4Pp1p/5K1k w - - 0 0"]
```

1.Qg2#/1.Qxg3=/1.Qh4 g2#/1.Qxh2+ K,gxh2=

Note that 5 pieces just stand around against 1.Qg4, which also ends the game, but in 1.5 moves - *still* too bad!

Comment: Note: If you drop the "*any* move ends..." condition, it is possible with a mere 5 pieces: https://www.yacpdb.org/#407710

Comment: I like it! Nice that white has just four options, each of which leads to a different outcome.

Comment: @DialFrost: BTW, your deleted solution is perfectly legit, if only a bit illegal. :-)